Alternate 100 Blue Eyed Islanders Riddle Conclusion - Contradictory Laws
In the 100 blue-eyed islanders riddle, there is a rule that if an islander figures out his eye color, he must leave the island. Doesn't that contradict the other rule that he can't inform anyone else of their eye color?
For example, if there's only 2 people on the island, and the guru announces that someone has blue eyes, so the first guy wonders why the second guy didn't leave.
The usual approach is that he didn't leave because the first guy also has blue eyes. But maybe, he didn't leave because the first guy doesn't have blue eyes but the second guy couldn't leave because then he'd be breaking the other rule not to inform anyone of their eye color! So, because of this conflict, he did nothing, not knowing what to do.
So that goes back to the first guy who now doesn't know his own eye color.

I think the rule should be interpreted as: an islander cannot directly inform another islander of their eye color, but it is OK if information is communicated when the islander chooses to leave the island. The point is that the only action an islander can take is to leave the island.

Imagine there were 10 people, 5 of whom have blue eyes. When the 5 blue eyed ones leave, the remaining 5 not-blue-eyed can conclude they are not blue eyed, but no-one told them that.

When the blue-eyed islanders leave, the others know they don't have blue eyes, but their colour could be any non-blue colour.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!  I think this post would be better if it included text listing the 100 blue-eyed islanders riddle.

I think you have a valid point.  Depending on how the question is asked or how strictly it is understood there is a loophole that breaks the solution.  For the solution to work the intended way the question should say something along the line that people never talk about eye colors and as a result nobody knows its own eye color.  Note that the xkcd version does not have this loophole but the link was added by someone else.

First, there must be one with blue eyes - "guru announces that someone has blue eyes". If someone see blue eyes and the other person does not leave it means he SEE blue eyes (If he would have seen black, he would immediately leave). If the first guy see hesitation, he knows that he also has blue eyes.
